# Spring hibernate configuration riddle

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration

I'm studying Spring and Hibernate now and I came across a riddle that I can't find a solution for. It's about configuring Hibernate for usage with Spring. Here's an example of Spring beans xml configuration from the Spring documentation:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>org/springframework/samples/petclinic/hibernate/petclinic.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

You can see here that the sessionFactory dependency (of the SessionFactory type I assume) of txManager bean  is covered by the sessionFactory bean, which is actually the LocalSessionFactoryBean class. But the point is LocalSessionFactoryBean does not implement the SessionFactory, so it can't be used for injecting that dependency. You can receive SessionFactory from the LocalSessionFactoryBean, but for that you need to call its getObject method, which is not done here.

And here is an example from my project, but this time with java configuration:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.luv2code.springdemo")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    
    // define a bean for ViewResolver

    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        
        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");       
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        
        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        
        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        
        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));     
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }
    
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        
        return props;               
    }

    
    // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int
    
    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {
        
        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);
        
        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        
        return intPropVal;
    }   
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        
        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        
        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        
        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }   
    
}
```

As you can see, the argument of the transactionManager method of type SessionFactory is autowired (which is strange, but that's not the point now) by the sessionFactory bean which is again the LocalSessionFactoryBean class, which doesn't implement the SessionFactory interface, so we have the same problem as with xml configuration.

I have seen such examples in several places on the internet, so I want to know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally. The documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) states:

> The Spring container recognizes that LocalSessionFactoryBean
> implements the FactoryBean interface, and thus treats this bean
> specially: An instance of LocalSessionFactoryBean is instantiated, but
> instead of being directly returned, instead the getObject() method is
> invoked. It is the object returned from this call getObject() that is
> ultimately registered as the sessionFactory bean.